What morphism is sent to a monomorphism by the left Kan extension ${\rm Lan}_{\Delta}\colon{\bf Set^\Delta\to\bf Set^{\hat\Delta}}$ along Yoneda?
For any small category $C$, let us write $\hat{C} = \mathbf{Set}_C$ for the presheaf category $\mathbf{Set}^{C^{\mathrm{op}}}$, and $y=y_C\colon C\to \mathbf{Set}_C$ for the Yoneda embedding. Consider the left Kan extension of $\mathbf{Set}$-valued functors along $y$:
$$
\operatorname{Lan}_y\colon \mathbf{Set}^C \to \mathbf{Set}^{\hat{C}}.
$$
Of course, the left Kan extension is pointwise in this case:
$$
(\operatorname{Lan}_y F)(X) = \operatorname*{colim}_{y(c) \to X} F(c).
$$
For brevity, we shall write $\hat{F}=\operatorname{Lan}_y F$ and $\hat{\theta}=\operatorname{Lan}_y \theta$ for any $F\colon C \to \mathbf{Set}$ and $\theta\in \operatorname{Mor}\mathbf{Set}^C$.
Question, tl; dr: I'm curious about good sufficient conditions on the quadruple
$(C, F\in \mathbf{Set}^C, G\in \mathbf{Set}^C, \theta\colon F\Rightarrow G)$ for the induced morphism $\hat\theta=\operatorname{Lan}_y\theta\colon \hat{F}=\operatorname{Lan}_y F \Rightarrow \hat{G}=\operatorname{Lan}_y G$ to be a monomorphism, i.e., a pointwise injective natural transformation. In particular, I am especially interested in the case where $C$ is the simplex category $\mathbf{\Delta}$, which consists of finite inhabited ordinals $[0]=1=\{0\},\, [1]=2=\{0,1\},\,\dotsc$ and maps preserving reflexive order.
An obvious necessary condition is that $\theta$ is pointwise injective, for $\theta$ is equal to the composite
$$
F\cong \hat{F}\circ y \Rightarrow \hat{G}\circ y\cong G.
$$
For general $C$, it is easy to see that this is not sufficient (we may take $C=\left\{ \bullet\leftarrow\bullet\rightarrow\bullet \right\}$ and remember that pushout $\mathbf{Set}^C \to \mathbf{Set}$ does not preserve monomorphisms). However, I have not been able to find a counterexample for the case $C=\mathbf\Delta$, nor a proof for its sufficiency.
One sufficient condition in the case $C=\mathbf{\Delta}$ is that $\theta\colon F\Rightarrow G$ is a "Reedy injection" in $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathbf{\Delta}}$. Here, though I'm not sure about the conventional terminology, let's say that a morphism in $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathbf{\Delta}}$ is a Reedy injection if it lives within the left class $\mathrm{Inj}^{\mathbf{\Delta}}$ of the Reedy weak factorization system $(\mathrm{Inj}^{\mathbf{\Delta}},\mathrm{Surj}^{\mathbf{\Delta}})$ corresponding to the weak factorization system $(\mathrm{Inj},\mathrm{Surj})$ on $\mathbf{Set}$.
By definition, a morphism $\theta$ is a Reedy injection if and only if, for each
$n \in \mathbb{N}$, the morphism
$\hat{G}(\partial \Delta[n]) \cup_{\hat{F}(\partial\Delta[n])} F[n] \to G[n]$ induced by the following diagram is injective:
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
{\hat{F}(\partial\Delta[n])} @>{\hat{F}(\mathrm{incl})}>> {F[n]} \\
@V{\hat{\theta}_{\partial\Delta[n]}}VV @VV{\theta_{[n]}}V \\
{\hat{G}(\partial\Delta[n])} @>>{\hat{G}(\mathrm{incl})}> {G[n]}
\end{CD}
$$
Sketch of the proof of the sufficiency. Reedy injectivity of $\theta$ ensures, for any simplicial set $X$ and any map $\partial\Delta[n]\to X$, the following map in
$\mathbf{Set}^{\left\{0\leftarrow 1\rightarrow 2\right\}}$ is Reedy injective if and only if $\hat\theta_X$ and $\hat\theta_{\partial\Delta[n]}$ is injective:
$$
\begin{CD}
{\hat{F}(X)} @<<< {\hat{F}(\partial\Delta[n])} @>{\hat{F}(\mathrm{incl})}>> {F[n]} \\
@V{\hat\theta_X}VV @V{\hat{\theta}_{\partial\Delta[n]}}VV @VV{\theta_{[n]}}V \\
{\hat{G}(X)} @<<< {\hat{G}(\partial\Delta[n])} @>>{\hat{G}(\mathrm{incl})}> {G[n]}
\end{CD}
$$
The Reedy injectivity of this map guarantees the injectivity of the induced map between the pushouts; therefore the induction proceeds and we may prove that $\hat\theta_X$ is monomorphic for any finite $X$. This extends to an arbitrary $X$ by a standard argument. $\blacksquare$
This sufficient condition is usable, but I'm not really sure if this is the best I can get. Particularly, I do not have a counterexample of the sufficiency of pointwise injectivity, so I'd like one or a proof of the sufficiency. If pointwise injectivity  is not sufficient, a better/tighter sufficient condition or a necessity proof of Reedy injectivity is also desirable.
